# IBM Watson how to change the hint from textbox

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant, web-chat

I created a Bot using the IBM Watson feature. I would like to know how to change the "tip" of the Web Chat text box (Example: "Type something" to "Type a message"). I looked in the related documentation about this, but I didn't find anything.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These strings are language dependent, hence you can override them as you see fit.
see
https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#updatelanguagepack